# how to seperate celery code into server and client side?

Tags: python, celery

Imagine that I've written a celery task, and put the code to the server, however, when I want to send the task to the server, I need to reuse the code written before.
So my question is that are there any methods to seperate the code between server and client.

Answer (score 0):

Try a web server like flask that forwards requests to the celery workers. Or try a server that reads from a queue (SQS, AMQP,...) and does the same.

No matter the solution you choose, you end up with 2 services: the celery worker itself and the "server" that calls the celery tasks. They both share the same code but are launched with different command lines.

Alternately, if the task code is small enough, you could just import the git repository in your code and call it from there